# invoking trigger on column update

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I have a condition where in a trigger should be invoked whenever a particular column gets updated in a table but not when any other column gets updated.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

A trigger gets invoked regardless of the fields changed, however you can use

```
IF UPDATE(mycol)
BEGIN
    -- logic goes here
END
```

to implement logic for a specific column.

Also take a look at COLUMNS_UPDATED function too.

Comment: Since SQL Server triggers are statement-level triggers rather than row-level triggers, I wondered how a single test UPDATE(mycol) could determine the update status for all rows.
It appears that an UPDATE statement will update a column either for all affected rows or none. This is because a column is considered updated if it is assigned a value in the UPDATE statement, no matter if the actual column's value is changed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger gets invoked on any update, but you can add some checking to process data only when your column has new value.

Answer (score 0):

trigger has only tree options ON INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE this means trigger will ge fired on every update command no mater what column is updated
Best Regars,
Iordan